# Celery wait for a task from another request

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, celery

Let's say there is a long task that takes 1 minute. When a user makes a request `/get-info` and waiting for the response it should return a result. I'm using `delay()`, `wait()` and everything works. Now I want if another 5 users make same request `/get-info` I want them 'connect' to the same task and get result once the task is finished. I'm trying to save task id in redis. But so far I'm having 2 problems.

1. If I use `AsyncResult()` and wait() the second request hangs.
2. If I use `AsyncResult()` and state, the first request hangs. How can I implement that?

```
@main.route('/get-info', methods=['POST'])
def get_info():
    if redis.exists('getInfoTaskId'):
        taks_id = redis.get('getInfoTaskId')
        task = add_together.AsyncResult(taks_id)
        result = task.wait()
        # result = task.state - if uncomment and comment the line above the first req hangs
    else:
        task = add_together.delay(23, 42)
        redis.set('getInfoTaskId', task.id, ex=600)
        result = task.wait()
        redis.delete('getInfoTaskId')

    return f"task result is {result}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by the same results? Just 5 users? Or all of them

Comment: By the way that you are doing is useless you are waiting for the task in the same route you don't need celery

Comment: Any suggestions how I can do that without celery? By saying same result I mean waiting for the result of a task which is already running. And return response with payload for all users once it's finished

Comment: Why are you not calling .get() on AsyncResult?

Comment: .get() or .wait() my second request hangs... I thought mb I need to add wsgi but now think the problem is that between a task and  .wait() can be one 'channel' once task is finished .wait() returns the result and close the channel, that's why second wait hangs. Probably if I want live updating I need web sockets or long polling (f.e. check every second if task is finished .state) that's my guess

Comment: So I suppose the best solution is provide /status/<task_id> endpoint, and make polling on front-end side